# Segmentation fault (core dumped) error for C program

Tags: c

I am trying to run below program in an online C compiler. But I get segmentation error. Can you help me fix this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char string[15] = "Strlwr in C";
    printf("%s",tolower(string));
    return  0;
}
```

Comment: Read http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/tolower/ It takes a single int as parameter, not char and not array. You probably want to use a loop on "string", which processes each in turn.

Comment: `tolower()` returns an `int`, and accepts a single `char`, not an array of `char`s.

Comment: Compile with all warnings enabled and treat the warnings as errors.

Comment: the posted code is missing the statement: `#include <ctype.h> which defines `tolower()`   Note: the function: `tolower()` handles a single char/int at  a time, not a NUL terminated array of chars (AKA a string) and returns a `int`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `tolower` incorrectly. This function returns `int` and gets `int` as a parameter (here is it's declaration: `int tolower(int c);`). What you want to do is call it on each `char` of your `char array`, and print each one:

```
    char string[15] = "Strlwr in C";
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++)
        printf("%c",tolower(string[i]));
```

Answer (score 5):

Following is the prototype of `tolower`

```
int tolower(int c);
```

You should pass an `int` or something like `char` which can safely convert to `int`. Passing `char *` (Type of `string`) like you do leads to UB.

To convert a string to lowercase, you need to convert each character separately. One way to do this is:

```
char string[15] = "Strlwr in C";
char lstr[15];
int i = 0;
do {
  lstr[i] = tolower(string[i]);
} while(lstr[i] != '\0');
printf("%s", lstr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Read cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/tolower It takes a single int as parameter, not char and not array.
You probably want to use a loop on "string", which processes each in turn.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    char string[15] = "Strlwr in C";
    for (i=0; i< sizeof(string)/sizeof(char); i++)
    {
        string[i]=(char)(tolower((int)string[i]));
    }

    printf("%s\n",string);
    return  0;
}
```

Output:

```
strlwr in c
```

Comment: Thanks a lot to all for your response. Understood the issue clearly now :-)